# Select ONLY the most common value in a table (if repeated)

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have three tables in MySQL: `photos`, `tags` and `photo_tags` with the following entries:

**photos:**

```
    ID |     NAME        | URL | CREATED |
    --------------------------------------------
     1 | Red flowers     | ... |   ...   |
    --------------------------------------------
     2 | Autumn trees    | ... |   ...   |
    --------------------------------------------
     3 | Rain in the city | ... |   ...   |
    --------------------------------------------
```

**tags:** (This table contains repeated tag names with some differences)

```
    ID |       NAME        |   URL   | CREATED |
    --------------------------------------------
     1 |      nature       |   ...   |   ...   |
    --------------------------------------------
     2 |      Nature       |   ...   |   ...   |
    --------------------------------------------
     3 |      NATURE       |   ...   |   ...   |
    --------------------------------------------
     5 |      summer       |   ...   |   ...   |
    --------------------------------------------
     4 |      Summer       |   ...   |   ...   |
    --------------------------------------------
     6 |      Ocean        |   ...   |   ...   |
    --------------------------------------------
```

**photo_tags:**

```
   PHOTO_ID | TAG_ID | CREATED |
   -----------------------------
       1    |    2   |   ...   |
   -----------------------------
       2    |    2   |   ...   |
   -----------------------------
       3    |    1   |   ...   |
   -----------------------------
       4    |    3   |   ...   |
   -----------------------------
       5    |    2   |   ...   |
   -----------------------------
       6    |    3   |   ...   |
   -----------------------------
       7    |    6   |   ...   |
```

As shown in the `photo_tag` table, the following tagIDs are used: `2: Nature`, `1: nature`, `3: NATURE` and `6: Ocean`.

If a tag is only used once (not duplicated) in the `photo_tags` table (for example Ocean) then I select it normally, but if it is repeated (for example Nature) then I want to select only the most used.

For example, if we rely on the `photo_tags` table and do a PHP `var_dump()`, it should be the following:

```
array(3) {

    // Duplicated tag, then select most common tag between (nature, Nature, NATURE)
    [0]=> array(1) { ["tag_name"]=> string(3) "Nature" }

    // Single tag, then select normally
    [1]=> array(1) { ["tag_name"]=> string(3) "Ocean" }

}
```

But my code:

```
 <?php

 $sql = ' SELECT t.`name`, COUNT( pt.`tagID` ) AS `pt_count` FROM `tags` t '.
        ' INNER JOIN `photo_tags` pt ON t.`tagID` = pt.`tagID` '.
        ' GROUP BY pt.`tagID` ORDER BY `pt_count` DESC ';

 $tags = [ ];
 $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
 $stmt->execute();
 while($row = $stmt->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
     $tags[] = [ 'tag_name' => $row['name'] ];
 }
```

It brings me all the tags whose tagID appears in the `photo_tags` table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a duplicated tag name exists, you want the most name only. Duplicated tags have the same name but different case (lower, upper, mixed).

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can do this with a common table expression. You would first join `tags` with `photo_tag` and count the number of occurences per tag, and then filter in the outer query on the most occuring tag, independantly of the case.

```
with cte as (
    select t.name, count(*) cnt
    from tags t
    inner join photo_tags pt on pt.tag_id = t.id
    group by t.id, t.name
)
select name
from cte c
where cnt = (select max(c1.cnt) from cte c1 where lower(c1.name) = lower(c.name))
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0f2bb2c4583bbe0222ae01a429a6789d)**:

```
| name   |
| :----- |
| Nature |
| Ocean  |
```

---

In earlier versions, the query gets longer. You can aggregate in a subquery, and then use a not exists conditition with a correlated aggregate query for filtering:

```
select name
from (
    select t.name, count(*) cnt
    from tags t
    inner join photo_tags pt on pt.tag_id = t.id
    group by t.id, t.name
) x
where not exists (
    select 1
    from tags t1
    inner join photo_tags pt1 on pt1.tag_id = t1.id
    where lower(t1.name) = lower(x.name)
    group by t1.id, t1.name
    having count(*) > x.cnt
)
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddlde](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=938cdaa370099596c03bd10f15f90589)**

Comment: Error: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'cte as ( select t.`name`, count(*) cnt from tags t inner join pos' at line 1

Comment: @HéctorManuelMartínezDurán: which version of MySQL are you using? Please run `select version();` and let me know the output.

Comment: mysql-5.7.24-winx64

Comment: @HéctorManuelMartínezDurán: I updated my answer with a query for your version.

Comment: Thank you very much @GMB it's work. Right now I am updating to the latest version of mysql

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). To work around the issue you could join on a more complex grouped subquery, either using the [`GROUP_CONCAT()` method](http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/sql-selecting-top-n-records-per-group), or [window functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html) if your version of mysql is high enough.

I think the real issue is bad data. You're better off normalising it so the table has no duplicate tags to begin with. Then you can use a simple join. Either lowercase every tag, aggregate them, then put a unique key on that column, or Use `LIKE` instead of `=` when matching for updates and insertions to that table.